# Como criar uma caixa dentro da outra usando div

Tags: javascript, html, css, webforms, flexbox

Tenho o seguinte codigo em html:

```css
.outer-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: black;
}

.inner-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
        <div class="inner-box"></div>
    </div>
```

Mas o quadrado de dentro não esta simetrico ou em paralelo com o de fora

Comment: Cara não entendi, o que vc quer dizer com "simetrico ou em paralelo", vc queria alinhar no centro? Não ficou claro como deveria ser o resultado final...

Comment: sim quero alinhar no centro

Comment: @hugocsl poderia rever essa duplicata porque ela não responde a duvida!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic pelo que eu entendi ele quer centralizar um elemento no outro, ele mesmo afirmou isso no comentário ai acima. Não resposta que marquei como duplicada tem 23 respostas sobre isso. Nem mesmo o próprio autor se manifestou quanto ao fechamento. Pq vc entende que ela não é duplicada?

Comment: @hugocsl o autor é outro assunto você sabe eles colocam ai somem e não dizem nada, em relação a pergunta as resposta anexadas não tem realmente o que ele precisa, talvez tenha outra mas essa ai não vejo que tenha, inclusive muito antiga poderia você que tem conhecimento aprofundado responder!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a pergunta é antiga, mas as repostas nem tanto, inclusive lá tem todos os métodos mais modernos de alinhamento com crossbrowser bem aceito. Se vc acha que ele está falando de aspect ratio adicionei mais 3 duplicadas

Comment: não tudo bem @hugocsl sem problemas

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tranquilo, vamos ver se o autor se manifesta, falando por mim eu não vejo problema em tirar o voto de fechamento se for o caso

Comment: eu quero postar uma imagem do resultado final, mas sou novo aqui no stack e estou tendo dificuldades para o fazer

Comment: fiz o upload no imgur.com, https://imgur.com/CnNpxEM

Comment: @hugocsl o fuso horario de onde estou não é o mesmo do Brasil

Comment: Entendi, @user221459 na verdade sua pergunta não tinha ficado muito clara, mas adicionei mais uma resposta como duplicada, com a primeira e com a ultima vc resolve o problema. Inclusive estude bastante a primeira pergunta, la tem todos os métodos de alinhamento no centro

Comment: @hugocsl muito  obrigado!!

Comment: consegui resolver com o seguinte codigo `.inner-box {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 10px solid #1785eb;   
}

.outer-box {
    border: 10px solid #f24c46;
    width: 50px;
}`